# Fix broken links in source code

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I recently took over a site with a lot of broken links, thanks to the old webmaster. Instead of pointing towards the domain, the links' targets are to the old (yes, we changed our hosting provider not knowing how bad this would end) provider's sub-sub-sub-domain for our hosting.

There are possibly hundreds of dead ends - and I would like to know if there's an "easy" work around. I was looking a curl or htaccess, but I never found anything on Google that matched what we needed.

Example:
Image file is hosted at *domain.dom/img/image.png* - however the old webmaster linked to *host.something.something.hostingprovider.dom/img/image.png* in the sourcecode and in the Wordpress-files/pages/posts.

Is it even possible to do so or do I have to go digging? I looked at some jquery or PHP too, trying to find a way to replace the link and source targets.

I do not have the possibility to do anything in the server config as we are on a shared server, unfortunately.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps a shell that gets info from img="" and similar common strings in code, doing the replace for the new domain.something.hosting.hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using wordpress maybe you can search and replace old domain with the new one:
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

or if you have few broken links you can use .htaccess 301 redirect: 
https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F